# Is there any generalization to say eigenvalue ($A+B$)=eigenvalue($A$) + eigenvalue ($B$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I get that in general this is not true. But is there any time when this can be true? Like we know from the concept of eigen vectors that if say $B = A^2 + 2A + I $then eigenvalue($B$) = eigenvalue($A^2$) + $2$eigenvalue($A$) + eigenvalue($I$).  Is there some other condition to say eigenvalue($A+B$) = eigenvalue($A$) + eigenvalue($B$)? Or how can we disprove that?

Can somebody provide with some idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expression $\operatorname{eigenvalue}(A)$ doesn't even make sense without more context. The only reason there's a statement we can make when $B$ is (e.g.) a polynomial in $A$ is that eigenvectors of $A$ are eigenvectors of $B$ and so we can compare the eigenvalues for any given choice of eigenvector $v$ of $A$. If $A$ and $B$ aren't related in this or some similar way, there's generally no way to match up the eigenvalues of $A$ with those of $B$ in a natural way.

Answer (score 2):

It works when, they have the same eigenvectors.  That is the case when $B$ is a polynomial of $A$, as you have discovered.